# Añadir nombres a elementos de una gráfica en python

Tags: python

Tengo un código en el que tengo una gráfica:

```
    dimension = random.randint(2,5) 
    plants  = range(dimension)
    customers = range(dimension)
    n=dimension
    

    random.seed(len(customers))
    customers_points   = [(random.randint(0,100),random.randint(0,100)) for j in customers]
    plants_points = [(random.randint(0,100),random.randint(0,100)) for i in plants]
    
######################################################################### GRAPH FUNCTION #################################################################

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def draw(selected):
    #We generate ramdonly production plants locations

    plt.plot([p[0] for p in plants_points], [p[1] for p in plants_points], 'ro')
    plt.plot([p[0] for p in customers_points], [p[1] for p in customers_points], 'bs')

    for (i,j) in selected:
        plt.plot([plants_points[i][0],customers_points[j][0]], [plants_points[i][1],customers_points[j][1]], 'g-')
        
    plt.xlabel("X coordinate")
    plt.ylabel("Y coordinate")
     
draw({})

######################################################################### USUAL DISTANCE FUNCTION #################################################################

import math
def distance(points, i, j):
    dx = points[i][0] - points[j][0]
    dy = points[i][1] - points[j][1]
    return math.floor(math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)*random.uniform(1.0, 1.2))


######################################################################### COSTS ARRAYS #################################################################
    cost  = [[random.randint(1,100) for i in plants] for j in customers] 
    fcost = [random.randint(1,100) for i in plants]



solver = pywraplp.Solver('UncapacitatedFacilityLocationProblem', pywraplp.Solver.CBC_MIXED_INTEGER_PROGRAMMING) #we use this one because it is free

###################################################################### DECISION VARIABLES #################################################################

x = { (i,j) : solver.BoolVar('x[%i, %i]' % (i, j)) for i in plants for j in customers} #Boolean variable is a variable which values are 0 or 1
y = { i : solver.BoolVar('y[%i]' % (i)) for i in plants }
#Remember that %i is to show integer value

############################################################################# MODEL #############################################################################

solver.Minimize(solver.Sum(fcost[i] * y[i] for i in plants) + solver.Sum(cost[i][j] * x[i,j] for i in plants for j in customers))

############################################################################# RESTRICTIONS #############################################################################
#Now we are going to write the restrictions into brackets because we have more than one

[ solver.Add(solver.Sum(x[i,j] for i in plants) == 1)  for j in customers ]
for i in plants:
    [ solver.Add(y[i] <= 1)  ]
    for j in customers: 
        [ solver.Add(x[i,j] <= y[i]) ]
        [ solver.Add(0 <= x[i,j]) ]
[ solver.Add(y[i] <= 1)  ]

solver.Solve()

print('Total cost = ', solver.Objective().Value()," euros ")    
selected = [(i,j) for i in plants for j in customers if x[i,j].solution_value() > 0.5]

print('Optimal path: %s' % str(selected))
draw(selected)
```

Y me genera esto:
Solución: `[(3, 0), (3, 2), (4, 1), (4, 3), (4, 4)]`
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es un problema de localizaciones en el que genero una gráfica con ejes que van de 0 a 100, que simulan ser coordenadas. A su vez, genero puntos aleatorios en dicha gráfica, tantos como plants y customers tengo (en este caso 5 de cada. Rojos: plants, azules: customers. Es decir, aunque un punto esté (según el eje de coordenadas en (supongamos) x=15 y=7), ese no es el nombre que quiero ponerle, me gustaría ponerle el nombre que le corresponde de la solución.

En la solución tengo por ejemplo que: (3, 0), (3, 2). Es decir que a la planta con nombre 3 van los customers numero 0 y 2, y en el gráfico se puede ver que hay un punto rojo que va hacia dos azules. Y lo mismo para: (4, 1), (4, 3), (4, 4): A la planta 4 van los customers 1,3,4.
Entonces me gustaría que cada punto y cada cuadrado tenga nombre.
¿Es posible?

Comment: ¿No lo tienen ya? ¿Los números que se ven en el gráfico qué cosa son?

Comment: Gracias por responder, he modificado la pregunta y añadido el código entero y he intentado explicar mejor lo que quiero